# Javascript: replace html class no-js with js

Tags: javascript, regex

Please explain following line of javascript code

```
(function (d, c) {
    d[c] = d[c].replace(/\bno-js\b/, "js");
})(document.documentElement, "className");
```

This line replace document element class name 
e.g. `class="no-js"` with `class="js"`

It's working fine, but I don't understand fully. 
`d[c] = d[c].replace` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs creates the function

```
function(d, c){
    d[c] = d[c].replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js");
}
```

It wraps the function with `()` to turn it into an expression, not a statement so this ways is callable, then it passes the arguments

```
(documentElement, "className")
```

In other words, executes the following code:

```
document.documentElement["className"] = document.documentElement["className"].replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js");
```

then retrieves the document's `documentElement` property and replaces its "className" according to the regex.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this is downvoted -- looks like a good question about mutability.

The reason is that strings are not mutable -- you can replace them with a new value, but you can't change them.

The net result is that

```
d[c].replace()
```

doesn't actually change the value, rather returns a new string with the updated value.

Only by doing an assignment of the returned value can you cause the source to change.

```
d[c] = d[c].replace(...)
```

"do the replacement, then use the replaced value as the original value"

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(d, c) {
    d[c] = d[c].replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js"); }
)(document.documentElement, "className");
```

The function is being invoked with two arguments. For clarity, we'll replace the variables in the function with the arguments that are being used to call the function.

```
// Find the element in the DOM identified by "documentElement"
// and access its "className" property, which controls the attribute in
// the markup called "class"
document.documentElement["className"] = 
// Then, take that same property (which is a string), and run
// .replace() on it, with a regex that says "find no-js separated by word
// boundaries", and replace that with js
// Finally, assign the result of that replacement to the original property.
document.documentElement["className"].replace(/\bno-js\b/,"js");
```